# Converting a button to a hyperlink

Tags: css

I have a button i want to convert the button into a hyper link, it works fine in Mozilla but in Internet Explorer it presses down as a button a click takes place ... so please help ....

```
Input.Button-Link, input.Button-Link:active
    {
        border: 0px;
        behavior: url("cssHover.htc");
        padding: 0px;
        width: auto;
        overflow: visible;
        background: transparent;
        color: Blue;
        text-decoration: underline;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    input.Button-Link:active
    {
         padding-right:50px;
         outline:0;

    }
    Input.Button-Link:hover
    {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

Comment: i need few events of a button as well so please help if u can ...

Comment: can you please elaborate on the events you want to capture on the input that you can't capture when using an anchor tag?

Comment: i just want to get this working in ie8 without the button pressing down so please help ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish but here are a few things you can try:

- Add styles to `input.Button-Link:focus`
- By using `<input type="image" src="button.gif" alt="Button" />`
- In conjunction with jQuery use [this](http://www.dfc-e.com/metiers/multimedia/opensource/jqtransform/) plugin to style your buttons

Answer (score 0):

You need JavaScript to solve this for IE.

Answer (score 0):

IE's behaviour here is hard-coded and can't be changed with CSS IIRC. The last thing that springs to my mind is to use display: inline instead of display: inline-block.

You might be better off using a link and a tiny bit of JavaScript.